# lib built in vs c++ 2005 How to use them in vs 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2005

I have the following problem: I have a library, let's call it library.lib that is written in VS C++ 2005. In VS 2017 I've got the following error when compiling:
LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'library.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries

Could you help me to solve it? Possibly I have to run VS 2005. However, I cannot install it. I have Windows 10 and the installer does not work.

Pol

Answer (score 0):

is there anybody here, who might help, the project cannot wait?